# CSS Select all img except for those in footer

Tags: css

```html
<div>
    <img>
</div>

<footer>
    ...
        <div>
            <img>
        </div>
</footer>
```

Is there any way to only select the first `img` element? I came up with

```css
img:not(footer img)
```

but it's not working, `document.querySelecorAll('img:not(footer img)')` says it's not a valid selector.

Dose anyone have an idea?

Comment: You want Javascript or with CSS only ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping CSS only

Answer (score 2):

You can do a wildcard selector that's not a footer as the parent in a child combinator.

```css
*:not(footer) > img {
  border: 3px solid red
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="" />
</div>

<footer>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="" />
</footer>
```